# How to print out the rectangle value in c#?

Tags: c#

```
 foreach(System.Drawing.Rectangle rect in _rectangleList)
 {
   MessageBox.Show(rect);
 }
```

I want to check the rectangle coordinates are stored correctly in the array. But I do not know how to print the value out.

Comment: So what does or doesn't this do? Have you tried reading and researching the result you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to access the properties that you want to display:

```
foreach(System.Drawing.Rectangle rect in _rectangleList)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"X:{rect.X} Y:{rect.Y} Width:{rect.Width} Height:{rect.Height}");
}
```

You could also simply set a breakpoint when you array is filled and check its contents with a debugger. If you are using Visual Studio, you can place the caret on the array and press Shift-F9 to view the contents (or select *Quick Watch* from the menu).

Comment: [`Rectangle.ToString()` already does that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Rectangle_ToString).

Comment: Yes, but in case the OP needs different values (like `rect.Left` or `rect.Right`) he can change his output accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Print coordinates in MessageBox :

```
MessageBox.Show("X:" + rect.Location.X + " Y:" + rect.Location.Y);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the rectangle height you would have to say
    rect.Height

Answer (score 0):

```
You can create your own extension method on the rectangle that will print out all the details that you . 

Check my example here.

 public static class RectangleExtensions
    {
        public static string Details(this System.Drawing.Rectangle rectangle)
        {
            var details = new StringBuilder();
            details.AppendFormat("Height: {0}", rectangle.Height);
            details.AppendFormat("Bottom: {0}", rectangle.Bottom);
            details.AppendFormat("Left: {0}", rectangle.Left);
            details.AppendFormat("Right: {0}", rectangle.Right);

            return details.ToString();
        }
    }
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var rectangle = new System.Drawing.Rectangle();


            Console.WriteLine(rectangle.Details());
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't have to do that, [`Rectangle.ToString()` already does that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Rectangle_ToString).